# Scaling with the built in database

Tags: opa

If you use the built in database that comes with Opa and create a single executable how is it possible to scale to multiple instances?  For example, you compile your app and you get myapp.exe, as I understand it that exe contains the database.  So if you want to run multiple instances of myapp.exe how do I synchronize the multiple instances of the database contained in each exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run several instances of `myapp.exe`, start an `opa-db-server`(installed by Opa package) with the `--db-local dbname` option.
Then run all your instances of `myapp.exe` with `--db-remote:dbname host` to connect to it.

If you need more in term of scalability, you can use the mongodb backend.

For further information, read https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/The-database